# Protected folder in yii folder is missing

Tags: yii, frameworks, xampp

Hello I'm new to `Yii framework`.

And I think I've been succeed to install it in my computer. But the problem is when I want to connect it to my `phpMysql` in `Xampp` I cannot find folder name `'protected'` which is needed to connect myproject to `yii`.

So anybody can help me about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If protected folder is not there, how you can say that you are successded in installing it. try installing it again. Try the below Yii2 template. Follow its guide to install it on your system properly. You must know composer for installing this template. 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Comment: Thank you. Yes i already check and i actually installing the wrong version of Yii. And I already installing the right one and the 'protected' folder now available. Thanks for the respond